# How to access documentation for ag-grid v9

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I want to implement tree data in angularjs with ag-grid v9 but I am cant access documentation for version prior to ag-grid v14
[here](http://54.222.217.254/javascript-grid-tree-data/) they have provided link for version prior to v14 but link gives 404 not found

We tried migrating to v14 but we are stuck at v10.1.x there are around 140 pages where ag-grid is used so it is not worth our time to migrate it and test it.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647378/ag-grid-2-3-2-documentation) solution as well but docs folder was removed after v3.